# create a range selection on click in a div

Tags: javascript, range, mootools

I have a div:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipiscing elit.</b> Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo.</div>
    when I just click in the area betwen the 2 Bold balises <b></b>, I want to create a selection of whole area.
```

I test:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();                                                            
   if (sel.rangeCount == 0) {
      return false;
   }
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var object = range.commonAncestorContainer.nodeName === '#text'? range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement: range.commonAncestorContainer;
range.setStart(object,0);
len = object.innerHTML.length;
range.setEnd(object, len);
```

But the selection is not good. Its set position 0 to my position of the click in the div, and not at the end of the string

Have you a solution? thanks

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, I think you are looking for this:

Try using object.**childNodes**.length; instead of object.innerHTML.length. You  may refer to the setEnd() Document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setEnd).

```
var sel = window.getSelection();                                                            
   if (sel.rangeCount == 0) {
      return false;
   }
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var object = range.commonAncestorContainer.nodeName === '#text'? range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement: range.commonAncestorContainer;
range.setStart(object,0);
len = object.childNodes.length;
range.setEnd(object, len);
```